# Change classloading policy for EJB jar in Websphere?

Tags: web-services, ejb, websphere, cxf

I'm trying to call webservice from my EJB jar module inside my EAR using CXF(It also contains utility classes used by other modules of my EAR). It is not properly calling and i'm getting `SOAPFaultException` from axis2 default from websphere plugin.

Same piece of code to call webservice, i put it in dynamic web project and make it as WAR with all supporting libs inside war as well changed the class loading policy as `Parent Last`, it is working fine.

Now i'm wondering how can i change EJB jar classloading policy as parent last in Websphere 8.5.5.0 ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the class loader mode on a per-EJB JAR basis, but all EJB modules are loaded by the application class loader (see the [Class loaders](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_classload.html) topic in the Knowledge Center), and you can change the class loader mode of the application class loader.  See the [Configuring application class loaders](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_classload_entapp.html) topic in the Knowledge Center for information on changing the mode of the application class loader.